# What's the significance of the animal transformations in The Once and Future King?

Tags: t-h-white, the-once-and-future-king

In T.H. White's *The Once and Future King*, Wart gets turned into a few different animals (a fish and a bird are the ones I remember). I never remember there being a real point to this (other than his brother Kay being jealous that Merlyn is paying attention to him?).

Am I missing something? What's the significance here?

Were they to teach him specific lessons?

Comment: Wiki's entry on the text offers a fair interpretation here: "Merlyn, knowing the boy's destiny, teaches Arthur (known as "Wart") what it means to be a good king by turning him into various kinds of animals: fish, hawk, ant, goose, and badger. Each of the transformations is meant to teach Wart a lesson, which will prepare him for his future life."

Comment: Each transformation had it's own lesson.  It might be better to break those into separate questions, as the explanation of each transformation can be huge.

Comment: The animal transformations were definitely part of the Arthurian legend *before* T.H.White's novel came along.

Comment: In addition, the 5th book of T.H. White's *Once and Future King*, titled *The Book of Merlin*, features one last transformation, this time of an aged Arthur, before he sets out to doom on the battlefield against his son Mordred. His old (now younger) mentor transforms him into a wild goose, and the lesson here has to do with White's sympathetic philosophical musings on anarchism.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Cliffs Notes](http://www.cliffsnotes.com/literature/o/the-once-and-future-king/book-summary/the-once-and-future-king-the-sword-in-the-stone) for the novel give a fairly strong overview of the sequence;

> Merlyn's lessons consist of transforming the Wart into different kinds
>   of animals. The boy's first transformation is into a perch, and while
>   swimming in the castle's moat, he meets Mr. P., a ruthless tyrant who
>   talks to him about power. At different points in the novel, the Wart
>   becomes a hawk, an ant, an owl, a wild goose, and a badger: Each
>   animal reveals to the Wart a different way of life, political
>   philosophy, or attitude toward war.

### Badger

> Of all the animals into which the Wart comes in contact, the badger is
>   the most obviously depicted as an embodiment of learning: He takes the
>   Wart to a room resembling an Oxford or Cambridge study hall, complete
>   with gowns, portraits of departed alumni badgers "famous in their day
>   for scholarship," and "a portrait of the Founder over the fireplace."
>   This is the first literal classroom into which the Wart has stumbled
>   and it is here that he will receive his most offbeat lesson, because
>   it is one about Man himself.

### Ant

> The ants introduce the Wart to a world of intense collectivism or
>   communism, which reveals to him the horrors of this political
>   philosophy. In a world where everyone (except the leader) is equal,
>   life becomes incredibly monotonous and static; examples of these
>   qualities in the ants' lives abound in this chapter. For example, the
>   "wireless broadcast" received by the Wart's antennae begins to "make
>   him feel sick" after an hour of its repetitions. None of the ants have
>   names (which might suggest personalities), but numbers (the Wart's is
>   42436/WD). All ants speak in the same "dead" and "impersonal" voice
>   and the narrator states, very bluntly, that "Novelties did not happen
>   to them." Their conversations, like their lives, are the same day
>   after day.

### Goose

> Before ending the episode, White inserts an anecdote concerning the
>   inherent dignity and natural leadership abilities of geese. This story
>   (which White says "ought to make people think") suggests the link
>   between the Wart's future as King and his present situation as a wild
>   goose: Knowing what he does about animals (everything), Merlyn would,
>   undoubtedly, want his pupil to learn of real leadership and how it
>   works. While the Wart does not hear the anecdote about the farmer and
>   his henhouse directly, the principle behind it — that leaders take
>   charge when a leader is needed — is embodied in the geese that the
>   Wart meets on his migration across the North Sea. The ants' leaders
>   exist merely to begin wars, but the admirals of the geese lead their
>   flocks above and beyond the boundaries that cause so much conflict.